# Enable SMS count on galaxy s3 lock screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens

When I first got my galaxy the at the lock screen I could see an icon with a count of unread text messages on the right side of the screen, but now it has disappeared and I did not see any settings for it in the lock screen menu under settings.  Is there a solution to this or was this the result of an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey man you can use this.
Notification LockScreen Widget (available for free in the [Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roymam.android.notificationswidget)).
It gives following features.

- View all dismissible notifications including missed calls, SMS, Facebook notifications, Gmail, etc.
- Launch the app directly from the notifications list.
- Combine multiple similar notifications into one notification with
  counter.
- Allow full original notification content as it appears on
  notifications bar.

Comment: I will be downloading that and giving it a shot, thanks!